# Listen for an event in powershell to run a function when a particular program is run?

Tags: powershell, events

Is it possible to subscribe to an event in powershell when a particular executable is run?

We have an application that hogs up memory and then causes the system to crash, and if I could attach an event that starts a timer when it starts running and just kills after a certain amount of time, that would fix the issue.

Comment: Would something like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-monitor-specific-process-creation/) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use task scheduler to trigger on an Windows Event.[Task Scheduler Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWzve.png)

Then you can add your powershell script as an action. Even delay the task if you like

Answer (score 0):

As Crusadin sugggests, have a script run when an eventlog entry is made.  I have just done the same thing here in work.